# Reading data from a file during download with Requests.response

Tags: python, python-requests, response, download

For context: The following version of my code works fine to download+write an entire image file to disk without reading any data from it before writing.

```
response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:
    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
            outfile.write(chunk)
        outfile.close()
```

My miserable attempts at reading the first chunk (containing the header of the file itself--not the http response, don't need that) with the following are failing.

```
with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:
    chunk1 = response.iter_content(chunk_size=256)

    # This gives: '<generator object Response.iter_content.<locals>.generate at 0x033E57E0>'
    print(chunk1)

    # This fails with error: 'TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'generator'
    outfile.write(chunk1)

    # Doesn't get to here anymore
    for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
        outfile.write(chunk)
    outfile.close()
```

I'm confused at this point. I don't understand why `chunk1` refuses to be written, while all chunks in the for loop in my first version of the code were written just fine. Is it the `print(chunk1)` statement changing `chunk1` somehow?

Is my use of the iterator incorrect?

I also don't know how to see what properties *chunk1* might have that would contain the data...

I also tried

```
print(response.content)
print(response.raw.data)
# No good: these both download the entire image file, THEN print it to console. 
# But they at least print the data itself instead of giving an object
```

The point of accessing the header before downloading everything is to stop the download entirely if the header reveals the image is undesirable for any reason. So I figure I have to read the chunks retrieved with *iter_contents* somehow.

But how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You confusion is in the use of a generator.  You can't save `chunk1`, you want to get the next piece from the generator using [`next`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#next) like:

#### Code:

```
outfile.write(next(chunk1))
```

#### Full Code:

```
import requests

url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mattupstate/flask-mail/master/flask_mail.py'
filename = 'flask_mail.py'

response = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if response.status_code == 200:

    with open(filename, 'wb') as outfile:

        # get the next chunk and save to disk
        outfile.write(next(response.iter_content(chunk_size=256)))

        for chunk in response.iter_content(chunk_size=256):
            outfile.write(chunk)
```

Note that you do not need the `close` when you a context manager (`with open(...`).

Comment: Thanks, going to review iterators now...!